# What is the best semantic and valid method to make drop shadow around whole #wrapper? on all side

Tags: css, xhtml

What is the best semantic and valid method to make drop shadow around whole #wrapper? on all side. horizontally can be fixed but vertically should be expandable.

Comment: Which browsers does it have to work with? Webkit and Gecko browsers have support for CSS3 shadows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to go with another, non semantic method for IE, [you could simply use CSS 3 for current (Webkit and Gecko based) browsers](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/):

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [css3.info](http://www.css3.info/images/box-shadow.png))</sub>

Of course, for IE you have a few other options.

- Use a single image for the background with a drop shadow.
- [Use some CSS trickery to have a few wrapper divs with some small borders that composite the shadow](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/onionskin/).

  [image]
- [Use javascript to create the drop shadow](http://cssgallery.info/javascript-drop-shadows/).

The last one has the advantage of given you the chance of using the CSS `box-shadow` on CSS3 enabled browsers, and the Javascript drop shadow on the rest (IE/Opera).

Comment: answer of question of last link , link is dead

Answer (score 1):

- Some JavaScript trick
- CSS3 or custom browser styles
- Use images around the #wrapper

Shadows can hardly be made semantically correct since they have no meaning. It's just a decoration (presentation) element.

Answer (score 1):

If the width is fixed I wouldn't use a wrapper I'd do like that:

```
<div class="box-header">
</div>
<div class="middle">
my content
</div>
<div class="box-footer">
</div>
```

For `top` and `bottom` classes I'd put the top and bottom shadows as a css background image.

Then I'd `repeat-y` a background image representing shadows on both sides of the box.

If you don't care about cross-browser compatibility, prefer using CSS3 properties.