# Images with rounded corners

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do sites like [these](http://www.wikihow.com) get to display images with rounded corners?

I checked with Firebug that the image being downloaded has sharp corners but the image being displayed has been modified somehow.

EDIT: I am referring to the rounded thumbnail pictures seen in the "Featured" articles section on the site mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's using an image overlay that [contains the curved borders](http://pad1.whstatic.com/skins/WikiHow/images/corner_sprite.png).

```
<img class="rounders2_img" width="103" height="80" alt="" src="http://pad2.whstatic.com/images/thumb/1/18/Shadow-of-a-Writing-Hand-1834.jpg/-crop-103-80-103px-Shadow-of-a-Writing-Hand-1834.jpg"/>
<img class="rounders2_sprite" src="http://pad1.whstatic.com/skins/WikiHow/images/corner_sprite.png" alt=""/>
```

The same technique is used generally for [drop shadows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132687/what-is-the-best-semantic-and-valid-method-to-make-drop-shadow-around-whole-wrap/2132750#2132750).

[image]

This is done because IE doesn't support many CSS 3 cool stuff, like [rounded corners](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/):

```
moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

Comment: Can't see anything on the link you posted. Can you please point to a resource explaining this overlay technique?

Answer (score 4):

You can also do that without images (read it somewhere, can't find the link anymore), by defining this in your style sheet:

```
#divallrounded { /* every border rounded */
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Would only work for images in Chrome/Safari: in Firefox it doesn't work for images, and in IE it doesn't work anywhere.

Comment: Only addendum from me is be sure to use the W3C (proposed) official version at the end, so : border-radius: 10px; --as for browsers not supporting a little rounded corner action, they'll catch up eventually, and until then a square corner or four is usually an acceptable design variance. (Viva la progressive enhancement.)

Answer (score 4):

There's several ways to achieve this, but in this instance here's how they did it:

If you look into the HTML, you'll see that the `<img>` is inside an `<a>`, and inside the same `<a>` is a second `<img>`, [corner_sprite.png](http://pad1.whstatic.com/skins/WikiHow/images/corner_sprite.png). If you look at this image you'll see that it's a series of white corners that fit various sizes. Using CSS they just overlay this image on top of the image whose corners they want to round so that the corners line up with the image of the appropriate size. The CSS file they do this in is [here](http://pad3.whstatic.com/extensions/min/?f=/skins/WikiHow/new.css&508). Search for "rounders" (a CSS beautifier might be useful here).

Answer (score 3):

Try out the **jquery** [**rounded corner plugin**](http://www.methvin.com/jquery/jq-corner-demo.html). I think that can do what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mistaken - check out the image for those big callouts -

http://pad3.whstatic.com/skins/WikiHow/images/actionBox_background_curl.png

... and here's the image that's sitting on top of the main container div (div.actions_shell) -

http://pad1.whstatic.com/skins/WikiHow/images/actions_top.png

... both include rounded corners.

Regarding the thumbnails in the 'featured' section, they're just overlaying a .png which is transparent except for white rounded corner cutouts:

http://pad1.whstatic.com/skins/WikiHow/images/corner_sprite.png

Comment: I believe Crimson is referring to the rounded thumbnail pictures under Featured Articles.

Comment: No, take a look at the images in the featured articles section.

Comment: gotcha - well, answer is still basically the same - they're just using images that include rounded corners, in the case of the featured thumbnails, the rounded corners are on a .png that's laid over the top.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no need whatsoever to use `<img>` tags to achieve what this site does. You can do it all with css (without using CSS3 properties). The trick to rounded corners is finding extra elements to hook your corner image onto in the css.

See:

[Sliding Doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) and 
[Custom Corners](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customcorners/)

Forget all these posts talking about `moz-border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius`. The CSS3 property is just called `border-radius` and all modern browsers support it.

Comment: But that's not the technique being used in the link. Also, the CSS3 `border-radius` is currently so sparsely implemented as to be worthwhile only as future-proofing and in *addition to* the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` (not to mention the `-khtml-` version).

Comment: My comment was that the browsers that support the `moz` and `-webkit` versions are the same ones that support the standard `border-radius` version, so it's fairly self defeating to use the verbose version.

Answer (score 0):

They are using images for rounding on the corners.  You can do this with `<img>` tags like they do, or give elements like `<div>`s and such background images with CSS.

Their site uses rounded images...not sure what you say in FireBug but they are rounded.  Alternatively instead of using separate `<img>` tags, you could use css background images for entire sections or for borders.

An alternative is [rounded corners in CSS](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/), but not all browsers are supporting this just yet.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I did not get it :(